# MySQL date query syntax

Tags: mysql

If I have a date column, example "2013-05-05", how do I select the previous record? I tried

```sql
SELECT DATE, percent_change
FROM aa
WHERE DATE >2012 -12 -31
ORDER BY DATE DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: do you want to select the previous record after ordering the record by date?

Comment: Er, "2013-05-05"  is not "2012-12-31"
!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that date is a unique key:

```
SELECT `date`, percentage_change FROM aa WHERE `date`>'2012-12-31' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then, to get the previous record:

```
SELECT `date`, percentage_change FROM aa WHERE `date`>'2012-12-31' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

And the record before that:

```
SELECT `date`, percentage_change FROM aa WHERE `date`>'2012-12-31' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

etc.

Comment: This returns the most recent entry, 2013-06-05.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking. I believe you are looking for the OFFSET syntax.  See edits above.

Answer (score 0):

To get the record before a given date, this should work:

```
SELECT DATE, percent_change 
FROM aa 
WHERE DATE < '2013-05-05' 
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a299/5)